# expressionengine endless redirect loop since upgrading to 2.6.1

Tags: expressionengine

Since upgrading my expressionengine site to version 2.6.1 when you go to admin.php you get stuck in an endless redirect loop. The problem is because the URL you get redirected to is missing an ampersand:

```
/admin.php?S=0&D=cpC=homepage
```

Should be:

```
/admin.php?S=0&D=cp&C=homepage
```

Anyone know why this is happening an if there is a fix?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in ExpressionEngine 2.6 and 2.6.1. You have to modify system/expressionengine/libraries/Core.php Line 407

change

```
ee()->functions->redirect(BASE.'C=homepage');
```

to be

```
ee()->functions->redirect(BASE.AMP.'C=homepage');
```

Comment: How does this get overlooked in 2.6 AND 2.6.1??